# How to reference an existing IAM policy in function definitions in `serverless.yml`?

Tags: amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I have a specific policy that I want to add to multiple lambdas in different services. How can I specify in the `serverless.yml` file the name of the already existing policy to avoid duplication of inline policies?
Currently, the best I could find is defining an anchor and referencing that, but I am looking for a "cross-service" solution.

```
anchors:
  idempotencyPolicy: &idempotencyPolicy
    Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - dynamodb:GetItem
      - dynamodb:PutItem
      - dynamodb:UpdateItem
      - dynamodb:DeleteItem
    Resource:
      - arn:aws:dynamodb:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/IdempotencyTable
.
.
.
  some-lambda:
    handler: handler.func
    memorySize: 512
    events:
      ...
    iamRoleStatementsName: some-name
    iamRoleStatements:
      - *idempotencyPolicy
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - cloudwatch:GetMetricData
        Resource: "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating that policy outside of serverless and assign it to a role that you can reference on each service using the role arn, just like it's shown here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/#custom-iam-roles.